MySQL Query performance - best partial match
I have performance issue on a query, potentiall wrongly written.
Dear all.
I have two tables.
One table "test_cdr" , with rougly 5M rows, contains three columns

POINT_TARGET | Contains called phone numbers
dest | should contain a destination identifier
DURATION | the duration of the call

Another table "codes" contains two columns

area_codes | contains a list of country prefixes
dest | contains the destination identifier

Now I need to puplate the test_cdr.dest by:

run every number in test_cdr.POINT_TARGET against the codes.area_codes
identify the best matches codes.area_codes
take the data inside codes.dest and copy it into test_cdr

like this, I can then sum the duration of each call per destination type.
I am, atm, using this query
UPDATE test_cdr AS main
JOIN (
    SELECT c.POINT_TARGET, t.dest
    FROM test_cdr c
    JOIN codes t ON c.POINT_TARGET LIKE CONCAT(t.area_codes, '%')
    WHERE c.dest IS NULL  -- Only update rows where dest is NULL
    LIMIT 1000  -- Adjust the batch size as needed
) AS matched ON main.POINT_TARGET = matched.POINT_TARGET
SET main.dest = matched.dest;

It only works with LIMIT and it returns roughly 10000 rows (every 20 seconds - pretty lame performance)
As soon as I remove LIMIT, the query runs but nothing is performed on the db (I see no disk activity, while with LIMIT there is disk activity).
Could you help me figure out the issue or maybe provide a better option?
Btw, I have used INDEXES.
Thank you.

Make sure you have an index on POINT_TARGET. Otherwise the LIKE query has to do a full scan.

LIMIT without ORDER BY makes the results non-deterministic.

Can you split the POINT_TARGET into two columns, POINT_TARGET_AREACODE and POINT_TARGET_NUMBER?

What is identify the best matches codes.area_codes - best match? Can you use table like (area_code1,dest) with index on (area_code1) and JOIN split_codes t ON POINT_TARGET =area_code1 ?

Does your area codes are detailed? Or maybe there exists a code which is a prefix of another code? The prefix length can be up to 7 digits...

With "best match" I suppose you mean the longest area code that matches the start of the called number?

@RobertKock yes!

Do you have a primary key on test_csrs?

Until you show an example of data, especially codes, it is hardly possible to talk about optimization. We need an example of data to consider optimizing the operation c.POINT_TARGET LIKE CONCAT(t.area_codes, '%').  Also, the best match is unclear, since for any match you assign the same dest.

here are some examples:
POINT_TARGET - 4141455582010 area_codes - 4141 dest - Switzerland-Fix-Swisscom
as there are shorter matches in area code, like 41, the mapping needs to happen only on the longest match

The column area_codes contains a list of area codes? In other words, the value within a single record may contain multiple area codes?

@RobertKock no, only a single area code per field.

Some primary key on test_cdr?

@RobertKock yes I have an id column

I'm not sure if this query improves the performance.
Furthermore, it updates all CDRs having destination NULL and maybe that's not what you want.
It does however take the longest area code in case of multiple matches.
For instance, if the dialed number is +3906123456 it considers area code +3906 (Rome) instead of +390 (Italy fixed).
Anyway, give it a try and please be gentle in case it's not useful.
UPDATE test_cdr AS cdrs
   SET cdrs.dest = (SELECT cod1.dest
                    FROM   codes AS cod1
                    WHERE  cod1.area_codes = LEFT(cdrs.point_target, LENGTH(cod1.area_codes))
                      AND  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                       FROM   codes AS cod2
                                       WHERE  cod2.area_codes = LEFT(cdrs.point_target, LENGTH(cod2.area_codes))
                                         AND  LENGTH(cod2.area_codes) > LENGTH(cod1.area_codes))
                    LIMIT 1)
 WHERE cdrs.dest IS NULL;

I'm quite convinced that
t.area_codes = LEFT(c.point_target, LENGTH(t.area_codes))

is faster than
c.point_target LIKE CONCAT(t.area_codes, '%')

UPDATE:
I suppose there's a unique key on codes.area_codes. In that case you can remove LIMIT 1 from the subquery since that query will never return more than 1 value.
Furthermore, if it doesn't find the corresponding area code, the destination will be updated to NULL which causes the same dialed number to be re-examined the next time.

this one is indeed faster than mine. I implemented also batch processes like this
`CREATE PROCEDURE update_in_batches(batch_size INT)
BEGIN
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE rows_affected INT DEFAULT 1;  -- To track the number of rows updated per batch.
-- Continue processing until no more rows are updated
WHILE rows_affected > 0 DO`


I recommend creating a procedure to paginate through the table. Here’s an example:
CREATE PROCEDURE update_when_dest_is_null()
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE batch_size INT DEFAULT 1000;
    DECLARE offset INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE total_rows INT;

    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO total_rows FROM test_cdr WHERE dest IS NULL;

    WHILE NOT done DO
        START TRANSACTION;

        UPDATE test_cdr AS main
        JOIN (
            SELECT c.POINT_TARGET, t.dest
            FROM test_cdr c
            JOIN codes t ON c.POINT_TARGET LIKE CONCAT(t.area_codes, '%')
            WHERE c.dest IS NULL
            LIMIT batch_size OFFSET offset
        ) AS matched ON main.POINT_TARGET = matched.POINT_TARGET
        SET main.dest = matched.dest;

        COMMIT;

        SET offset = offset + batch_size;

        IF offset >= total_rows THEN
            SET done = TRUE;
        END IF;
    END WHILE;
END

Be sure to test this procedure thoroughly before using it in a production environment.

after suggestion from Konteye I modified the query:
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE update_when_dest_is_null()
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE batch_size INT DEFAULT 1000;
    DECLARE offset INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE total_rows INT;

    -- Get the total number of rows where dest is NULL
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO total_rows FROM test_cdr WHERE dest IS NULL;

    -- Start the loop to process updates in batches
    WHILE NOT done DO
        -- Start a transaction
        START TRANSACTION;

        -- Update the test_cdr table in batches
        UPDATE test_cdr AS main
        JOIN (
            SELECT c.POINT_TARGET, t.dest
            FROM test_cdr c
            JOIN codes t ON c.POINT_TARGET LIKE CONCAT(t.area_codes, '%')
            WHERE c.dest IS NULL
            LIMIT batch_size OFFSET offset
        ) AS matched ON main.POINT_TARGET = matched.POINT_TARGET
        SET main.dest = matched.dest;

        -- Commit the transaction
        COMMIT;

        -- Update the offset for the next batch
        SET offset = offset + batch_size;

        -- Check if we've processed all rows
        IF offset >= total_rows THEN
            SET done = TRUE;
        END IF;
    END WHILE;
END$$

DELIMITER ;

It is still very slow, but processing.
